# What does it mean to have symmetric quantiles?

Tags: regression, interpretation, quantiles, quantile-regression

I'm using quantile regression for my paper, and my results are symmetric i don't understand what that means. Please explain the symmetry of quantiles and how does this effect the results and how to interpret the them.
I've performed the 2 tests eviews provieds for quantile regression, slope equality test and symmetric coefficient test.the p-value is under 0.05 ,however i don't understand what it means. Or how to interpert the results

Comment: How do you know you have symmetry?

Comment: I suspect this is  a homework question.

Comment: How is it possible that you can claim your "results are symmetric" and not know what "symmetry of quantiles" is?  We really need your specific results to be sure we understand your question correctly.

Comment: First think sbout what symmetric quantiles means for a single univariate distribution, then think about what it implies for each conditional distribution in the regression(s)